# What does "the balcony is really far away" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

Yesterday, I watched MasterChef America. There were two teams competing in the challenge of cooking and serving food at a football game. There were 100 voters and the red team won the blue team by 51 to 49.

Since the blue team lost in the competition, they had to do the pressure test where they cook against each other and only few of them would stay in the game. Before the pressure started, one of them said "I know we lost only two points but in the competition it doesn't matter how many points we lose. They balcony is really far away."

What does "the balcony is really far away" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Lol `the balcony is really far away` is no phrase. `Balcony` is the part of the contest.

In `MasterChef America` the cooking stations is overlooked from the `balcony`.

At the time of `Pressure Test` not all members need to participate, few of the members from the loosing team may sit in the `balcony`. So I guess the chef might have meant the balcony for him tough to reach, or something like that. Have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MasterChef_%28U.S._TV_series%29#Format)

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle hint of the word "Balcony" here. If I remember correctly, in Masterchef US kitchen, the winners are sent to stand and watch from upstairs, while the others cook below, during the pressure test. This might be a reference to that "balcony", which is the viewing area upstairs.

Also, it can be considered an expression which roughly means *that the best seats in the house are already gone*, or simply put, *the blue team is now very far from being victorious*.

The expression has its roots in the "*balcony seats*" being considered the best ones in a theater.

Also notice the sentences said by the blue team:

> I know we lost only two points but in the competition it doesn't
>   matter how many points we lose. They balcony is really far away.

It implies that it doesn't matter if you lose by two points, or twenty, or more. When you lost by just two points, and say that the "balcony is really far away", it means you've truly lost.